# What is 抢红包，订阅开奖提醒？

Tags: translation

I could not find a better answer to express the red envolope meaning behind Chinese culture.

Comment: Is that a complete sentence, or any more context you can provide?

Comment: It's a button or sentence appear on a page. I just want to make some local translations. :)

Comment: Could you please help to proofread the strings appeared in the first  banner? http://www.hanbridgemandarin.com/
Thank you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this reads as a question about expressing Chinese concepts in English, and thus the focus of the question seems to be on English.

Answer (score 3):

抢红包:

Actually, you can understand "抢红包" like this: many people are scrambling a gift happily.

FYI: usually "red envelope" means a small package with money :)

订阅开奖提醒: you can understand it like this: subscribe it and it will send a notice to you when will begin to 抢红包.

Answer (score 1):

I did a little research and found this on "Chinese wikipedia", and translated it for you:

> Giving out 红包 is a Chinese convention during New year (Festival). In China the color red stands for joy, luck and happiness.
>
> Giving out 红包 to someone (usually 18-) means bringing luck and wish to them. And the money in it is only to make kids happy.

Below is the original article:

派"红包"是华人新年的一种习俗，华人喜爱红色，因为红色象征活力、愉快与好运。
派发红包给未成年的晚辈（根据华人的观念，已婚者就算成年），是表示把祝愿和好运带给他们。红包里的钱，只是要让孩子们开心，其主要意义是在红纸，因为它象征好运。因此，在分派红包的长辈面前打开红包，是不礼貌的做法。